# When to stop an ad campaign?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sequential-analysis

I have a campaign and I am trying to decide whether to terminate or not, with profit maximization in mind. There is cost associated with every time the ad is shown, and a reward once it converts (viewer clicks on the ad and subsequently performs an action). Let $p_+$ be the conversion rate (conversions over impressions) required to make profits, and let $\theta$ be the unknown true conversion rate of the experiment.

I would like to know how to decide that $\theta \leq p_+$. i.e I would like to know how to decide that the ad is never going to make profits given that I know the breakeven conversion rate $p_+$.

Edit: This edit is inspired by Adrian's answer. I have not posted it as an answer since I am not yet sure whether it is the correct approach.

Attempted solution: Let $Y$ be the total number of conversions, and $N$ be the total number of impressions. Then we assume a prior of $Beta(1, 1)$ of which posterior is $Beta(Y + 1, N - Y + 1)$. At this point we decide to stop the ad once $Pr(x > p_+) < \epsilon$, where $x \in X \sim Beta(Y + 1, N - Y + 1)$ and $\epsilon$ is some threshold (say $\epsilon = 0.05$). Where the probability can be calculated with 
$$
Pr(x > p_+) = 1 - \frac{\int_0^{p_+} t^Y(1-t)^{N-Y}dt}{\int_0^1 t^Y(1-t)^{N-Y}dt}
$$.

Questions:

1. Are there any errors with the described reasoning?
2. Is $Beta(1, 1)$ a good choice for the prior?
3. Is $Pr(x > p_+) < \epsilon$, where $ x \in X \sim Beta(Y + 1, N - Y + 1)$,  the correct way to think about when to stop?
4. What about non bayesian approaches?
5. How do bayesian vs non bayesian approaches compare in this context?

Disclaimers:

- I started to study statistics very recently. So please let me know if I need to clarify anything I mean. I am not sure that I am using standard notation.
- I am not yet sure about the correct practices for stack exchange. Am I supposed to make separate posts for each of the questions I asked? I am allowed to update the question so often in order to evolve with the answers received? (Answer this questions only if I am not complying with the correct practices).

Comment: Should this one be marked as self-study or tax-free campaign-contribution? :-)

Comment: It is unclear how any statistical test could be applied, because you don't supply any relevant information. Could you explain why you *ever* would want to stop a profitable ad? Are you suggesting that $p_0$ is not a fixed rate (as implied in the text) but *varies over time*? If so, then what do you know--or can assume--about *how* it varies with time?  An additional point of confusion is that the mention of "multiple tests" suggests an entirely different problem where you won't stop an ad, but will choose among two or more different ads. What's really going on?

Comment: I apologize for being so vague. I edited the question to make it more specific. Please let me know if any additional clarification is required.

Comment: That was helpful, thank you. But I wonder whether you actually wanted to write that $\theta$ is the *breakeven* conversion rate. It is neither meaningful nor statistically decidable whether $p_{+}$ exceeds the true rate.  Could you edit the post to clarify this important point?

Comment: Did the edit help?

Answer (score 1):

You have a conversion rate $\theta \in \left[0, 1\right]$.  Are you able to express your profits as a function of that rate?  If so, let $\pi\left(\theta\right)$ denote your profit function. Perhaps it makes sense to let
\begin{equation*}
\pi\left(\theta\right) = \theta \, v - c
\end{equation*}
where $c$ is a cost and $v$ is the value of a conversion. In that case your breakeven $\theta$ is given by $p_+ = \frac{c}{v}$.

One approach could be to start with a prior over $\theta$, and continue the campaign as long as $\mathbb{E}\left[\theta\right] > p_+$, where you update your posterior over $\theta$ with each new impression.  You could use a beta prior and a binomial likelihood, for example.

Comment: I wonder, though -- is that the optimal stopping rule if the objective is to maximize the present value of expected profits (discounted at some rate > 0)?

Comment: Thank you Adrian. To your question, Yes. What you described is how I thought of $p_+$.